# How to summarize some duplicates rows with one specific value?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

My data:

```
Plant   n   Plot1   Plot2   Plot3
A   5   1       1
A   5   1       1
A   5           1
A   5           1
A   5           1
B   4   1       
B   4   1           
B   4       1
B   4   1
C   3           1
C   3           1
C   3           1
```

Expecting result:

```
Plant   n   Plot1   Plot2   Plot3
A   5   1       1
B   4   1   1   
C   3           1
```

I have tried using 'group_by' for Plant and n, but I haven't been able to find the correct code to summarize the values in Plot1 to Plot3.
I want, if the value 1 appears in Plot1, 2 or 3 in some of the iterations, then it will still be 1 for the summary value. And if it is empty, then it is left blank.

Comment: could you please show the data using dput(df)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
summarise(df, across(starts_with("Plot"), ~ as.integer(1 %in% .x)), .by = Plant)
```

Output:

```
  Plant Plot1 Plot2 Plot3
1     A     1     0     1
2     B     1     1     0
3     C     0     0     1
```

The problem with using `distinct()` in this case (which is what you'd ordinarily do to remove duplicate rows) is that it gets multiple rows per column. `distinct(df, Plant, .keep_all = TRUE)` keeps one per Plant, but it keeps the first row for each Plant, which doesn't work for Plot 2.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Plant = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  n = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3),
  Plot1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
  Plot2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  Plot3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1)
)
```